# How to use cdc_ncm driver instead of cdc_acm in ModemManager

Tags: ubuntu, networking, drivers, network-interface

In Ubuntu 16.04 I try to use a USB modem in NCM mode. But ModemManager uses automatically the cdc_acm driver which creates a PPP interface.

lsusb shows 6 cdc_acm devices and 1 cdc_ncm device. How can I force ModemManager to use the cdc_ncm driver?

mmcli -m 0 output shows that both drivers are loaded.

Comment: I'm having this same problem. I have other modems that use `qmi_wwan` and those create a `/dev/cdc_wdmN` device which ModemManager uses as the primary port. The device I'm working with right now shows `cdc_acm, cdc_ncm` as the loaded drivers, a serial port as the primary port, though it did create a `wwan0 (net)` device and ModemManager identifies it with the modem

Comment: @bobpaul were you able to solve the problem? Running into the same problem myself.